# Output of a Currency conversion app keep returning the value to none

Tags: python

I am currently working on making a currency converter using the frankfurter app. However after continuous debugging, I keep getting the output as "None"

[image: Coming up as none]

[image: Debug work fine]

This is the current code:

api.py:

```py
import requests

BASE_URL = "https://www.frankfurter.app"

def get_currencies_list():
    response = requests.get(f"{BASE_URL}/currencies")
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        return list(data.keys())  # Assuming the API response is a dictionary with currency codes as keys
    else:
        # Handle API error or request failure gracefully
        return []

# You can then call this function to get the list of currency codes
currencies_list = get_currencies_list()


def get_latest_conversion(from_currency, to_currency):
    response = requests.get(f"{BASE_URL}/latest?from={from_currency}&to={to_currency}")

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        rate = data.get("rates", {}).get(to_currency)
        if rate is not None:
            return rate
    return None  # Return None if there's an error or the rate is not available


def get_historical_conversion(date, from_currency, to_currency):
    formatted_date = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    response = requests.get(f"{BASE_URL}/{formatted_date}?from={from_currency}&to={to_currency}")

    print("API Response Content:")
    print(response.text)  # Print API response content for debugging

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        rates = data.get("rates")
        if rates and to_currency in rates:
            rate = rates[to_currency]
            return rate

    print("Error: Unable to fetch historical conversion rate.")
    return None
```

app.py:

```
import streamlit as st
from api import get_latest_conversion, get_historical_conversion
from currency import format_conversion_result
from api import currencies_list

st.title("Currency Conversion App")
amount = st.number_input("Enter the amount to convert")
from_currency = st.selectbox("Select the source currency", currencies_list)
to_currency = st.selectbox("Select the target currency", currencies_list)
date = st.date_input("Select a date (for historical conversion)")

# Create a button to trigger API calls
if st.button("Convert"):
    if date:
        result = get_historical_conversion(date, from_currency, to_currency)
    else:
        result = get_latest_conversion(from_currency, to_currency)

    if result is not None:
        st.write(format_conversion_result(result))
    else:
        st.write("Conversion result not available or there was an error.")
```

currency.py

```
# Define a list of currency codes
currencies_list = ["USD", "EUR", "GBP", "JPY", "AUD", "CAD", "CHF", "CNY", "INR", "SGD"]

def format_conversion_result(result):
    # Implement the function to format the conversion result
    pass
```

frankfurter.py

```
import requests

BASE_URL = "https://www.frankfurter.app"

def fetch_currencies_list():
    # Implement the function to fetch the list of available currencies
    pass

def fetch_latest_conversion(from_currency, to_currency):
    # Implement the function to fetch the latest conversion rate
    pass

def fetch_historical_conversion(date, from_currency, to_currency):
    # Implement the function to fetch historical conversion rates
    pass
```

As seen in the code, there is quite a bit of debugging but I can't see to figure it out, help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the `format_conversion_result` function in your actual code really just a `pass`? If so, that function always returns `None`. (A Python function returns `None` if it finishes execution without encountering a `return` statement.)

Answer (score 0):

As @slothrop mentioned, format_converison_result was bugging due to the pass function which therefore always returned as None.

Update the currency.py file:

```
# Define a list of currency codes
currencies_list = ["USD", "EUR", "GBP", "JPY", "AUD", "CAD", "CHF", "CNY", "INR", "SGD"]

def format_conversion_result(result, amount, from_currency, to_currency, date=None):
    if date:
        date_str = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        conversion_message = f"The conversion rate on {date_str} from {from_currency} to {to_currency} was {result}."
    else:
        conversion_message = f"The latest conversion rate from {from_currency} to {to_currency} is {result}."

    converted_amount = amount * result
    inverse_rate = 1 / result

    message = (
        f"{conversion_message} "
        f"So {amount} in {from_currency} corresponds to {converted_amount} in {to_currency}. "
        f"The inverse rate is {inverse_rate}."
    )

    return message
```